# count stars from an image , is this possible with mathematica?

Tags: image-processing

I was wondering if "MATHEMATICA" with the amount of instructions it has has any to count points in an image, in this case stars, I imagine comparing contiguous pixels and if they are not black mark 1 or 0 if not with some percentage precision.
There is some instruction capable of processing an image under these conditions.
This concern stems from a documentary by the hubbe telescope, which points to a certain place and the program's announcers say that there are 30,000 galaxies that are seen as points of light.
I would appreciate some example.
I attach some images

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If  run `MorphologicalComponents[Binarize[...]]` ( replacing `...` by your first image) MMA tells me there are 500 components.  Is that enough to get you started ?

Answer (score 2):

A minimum solution is:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAfcx.jpg"]; (*first image above*)

ComponentMeasurements[
  Binarize[img],
  "Count"] // Length (*returns: 1018*)
```

`Binarize` converts it into a black and white image.  There are options to control the thresholding.

`ComponentMeasurements`  with the property `Count` returns a list of rules describe the components and the number of pixels.  In many cases, we get 1 pixel, but there are some larger values

`Length` just determines how many entries are in the returned list, i.e., how many components.

Certainly, one could also use `MorphologicalComponents` as well for a task like this.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I didn't answer before I was sick.